# PLT Scheme Memory

Tags: racket

So I need some help with implementing a Make-memory program using Scheme. I need two messages 'write and 'read. So it would be like (mymem 'write 34 -116) and (mymem 'read 99) right? and (define mymem (make-memory 100)).....How would I implement this in scheme? using an Alist???I need some help coding it. I have this code which makes make-memory a procedure and when you run mymem you get ((99.0)) and what i need to do is recur this so i get an alist with dotted pairs to ((0.0)). So any suggestions on how to code this?? Does anyone have any ideas what I could do to recur and make messages Write and read??

```
(define make-memory
  (lambda (n)
    (letrec ((mem '())
             (dump (display mem)))
      (lambda ()
        (if (= n 0)
            (cons (cons n 0) mem) mem)
            (cons (cons (- n 1) 0) mem))
      (lambda (msg loc val)
        (cond
          ((equal? msg 'read) (display 
                               (cons n val))(set! n (- n 1)))
          ((equal? msg 'write) (set! mem 
                                     (cons val loc)) (set! n (- n 1)) (display mem)))))))


(define mymem (make-memory 100))
```

Yes this is an assignment but I wrote this code. I just need some help or direction. And yes I do know about variable-length argument lists.

Comment: There are several possibilities, but it seems like this might be homework. If so, what constraints do you have? Can you use any functions you want, or only certain ones you know about? Same for language features - do you know about variable-length argument lists?

Comment: This SMELLS like a homework problem, even without the "PLT Scheme" mentions.

Answer (score 2):

Is the class you're in using the Design Recipe a la [How To Design Programs](http://www.htdp.org)?

If so, it looks like you're on step one.

If not: can you specify the behavior you're looking for using a set of examples, and then turn them into test cases?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that what you need is `make-vector`.

Answer (score 0):

Two places that seem to be errors `(cons n 0)` and `(cons (- n 1) 0)`
That is why you are getting (0 . 0)s, as you are consing n or n-1 onto 0, not a list.